# Does Keras or Tensorflow have built in NaN protection?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I have a network where the losses took a sudden bad turn during training.  Upon investigating, I found that one weight had become NaN.  The thing I can't figure out is that when I ran data through it (evaluate) the output was not NaN. To make sure the weight was actually connected to the output, I changed its value, and the output changed. To the point of my question: when I changed the weight from NaN to 0.0, I got the same output (as with NaN, but different from the other value).  How is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You could simply be overtraining your model. With more and more training examples, your error will decrease and the log of your loss function will approach negative infinity. This overflow could cause the weights to become NaN. Try training on increasing amounts of training samples and see if you can find the “cutoff” where the weights become NaN. Let me know if this helps!